# need to login 2 times

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In my Drupal installation I often need to login 2 times to get logged in.

This is the case when I go exactly this way:

1. open a new incognito window in browser (in my case Chrome)
2. try to login -> login failed with no message
3. try to login 2nd time -> logged in
4. close the window WITHOUT logout
5. open a new incognito window in browser and try to login -> login failed

When I logout and try to re-login, the login works.

There are some more randomly cases where the login doesn't work too at the first time. But these cases I can't describe exactly.

In Drupal log and Apache log I don't get any message after a failed login.

Where can I start my search to solve this? Or does anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session cookies are stored by drupal to confirm users as being logged in. Check the developer tools in chrome to asses whether a cookie has been or was meant to be stored. Icognito Mode makes a point of treating cookies with deference (might also be the general settings of your browser).

Comment: OK, I got it. Cookies was a good keyword. I didn't changed anything about cookies in my Drupal installation. The only thing that could be due to this was the modul secure_pages. I switched it of and the login doesn't make any problem.

But now I have to find the problem within this module/settings). Or I need another solution for SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your cookie domain settings.php. Depending on your hosting or setup this sometimes needs to be done to make sure cookies are working correctly.

Basically you will add a line like

```
$cookie_domain = '.my_site.com';
```

Do not add a trailing slash and do not remove the leading period (this is documented and commented out in settings.php, do a find for $cookie_domain and you should see it.

https://drupal.org/node/1844574